# How do i select the last row and a certain column of the datagridview to use in an If condition ?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview and the last row states the year and month. How do i select the last entered month to check if its the last month of the year and then increment the year accordingly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you want to get the lastrow of the datagridview,you can use if condition like

```
If datagridview.Rows(datagridview.Rows.Count - 1).Columns("yourcolumn").ToString = yourcondition Then
'Your Code
End If
```

here `datagridview.Rows.Count - 1` will be the last row index.hope this helps.

Comment: In your code it says here that Columns is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow'